# Selector for no children?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How could I make the last div always red no matter the depth of elements?

output:

[image]

```css
.box > div > div > div > div {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    The first paragraph.
    <div>
      The second paragraph.
      <div>
        The third paragraph.
        <div>
          The fourth paragraph. (is red)
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem possible with current CSS selectors without resorting to the solution in @rlemon 's link. `:isempty` selects on nothing in the tag, including text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge I don't think it is possible without editing your html structure (id/class) at all.

I think the best solution would be javascript

```
let element = document.querySelector('.box')
let temp = element
while (temp = temp.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]) {
    element = temp
}
element.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

This script gets the box element and loop through all of his div children to the last one and then sets the background color to red.

Important to note that this will set the box element red if it has no child. You could do a quick check before setting the background color depending on your needs.

```
if (element !== document.querySelector('.box')) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Do this to the div:

```
<div class="whatever">
```

then add css;

```
.whatever
{
        background: #ff0000;
}
```